# Calling a Parameter as State in React

Tags: function, reactjs, parameters, state

I have a checkbox in react that calls a function with its state as the parameter.

```html
<p>
  <input
    type="checkbox"  
    name="hobbies"
    checked={this.state.All}
    onChange={this.checkHobbies.bind(this, "all")}
  />
  All Hobbies
</p>
```

My offending code lies here:

```js
checkHobbies(name) {
  this.setState({
    name: !this.state.name,
  });
}
```

SetState however, interprets name as an actual state rather than the variable being passed in the parameter, which in this case is a variable called "all". How would I make it so that the code would interpret the function as:

```js
this.setState({
  all: !this.state.all
});
```

Comment: do you mean [name]: !this.state[name]  ?

Comment: @Utro yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
checkHobbies(name) {
  this.setState({
    [name]: !this.state[name],
  });
}
```

if the value passed as 'all' then the seState would be interpreted as below.

```
this.setState({
  all: !this.state.all
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
checkHobbies(name) {
  this.setState({
    [name]: !this.state[name],
  });
}
```